# JQuery targeting all Textarea is not working with .keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three text box on a page and each one has a different `ID` `Class` and located in different `div`. I am trying to target all the `<textarea>` on the page and running a function that will `dosomething()` if a user is still typing in the textarea. The problem is that it is only working on the `#first` textarea and the rest are just ignored. Below is the code I am using. Thanks!

```
$('#first, #second, .third').keyup(function(){
 if ($('#first, #second, .third').val()){
     alert("User is typing");
 }})
```

Comment: it's working fine for me

Comment: Do you have textboxes (i.e. `input type=text`) or do you have `textarea`s?

Comment: I have `<Textarea>`

Comment: Everything goes to haywire when alerts are involved. Use `console.log()` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just target the elements by specifying the tag name in your selector:

```js
$('textarea').on('keyup', function(e) {
  console.log('typing')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
<div>
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
<div>
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[`$.val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

> Get the current value of the first element in the set of matched elements.

Your check is only seeing if the first element in your selection has a value.  You probably want to do:

```
$('#first, #second, .third').keyup(function(){
    if ($(this).val()) {
        alert("User is typing");
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#first, #second, .third').forEach(function(txtarea){
 $(txtarea).keyup(function(){
    if ($(this).val()){
       alert("User is typing on THIS textarea");
    }
 })
})
```

I don't know why, but i had some issues with the textarea too. For me, some events are not fired on the textarea.
  In this code, i made a loop for each textarea and ser the keyup listener.
  Javascript have a lot many to do things. :)

Comment: I still can't find an explanation, why this code would work differently than OP's code.

Comment: It's because you are don't using the selection css on the if, with the jQuery, and is getting value of each textarea. I'm just trying to help.